# Two size() calls to the same object returning different values

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator

I have a function for inserting a value into an empty map of a map of a vector. (That specific structure works for my needs of some complex sorting for rendering objects).

However, my data appears to be getting lost at some point in the structure as I'm adding things to it.

My method code (with a little context) is here:

```
typedef unsigned int ComponentUID;

//For the purposes of this example, assume the map is completely empty
std::map<ComponentUID, std::map<float, std::vector<GameObjectPtr>>> renderOrderMap;

void Render::addGameObjectToMap(GameObjectPtr objectPtr) {

    //Expose the pointer for ease of use
    GameObject *object = objectPtr.get();

    //Set up component local variables
    RenderComponent *component = object->getRenderComponent();
    ComponentUID uid = component->getComponentUID();

    //Get object's render level (arbitrary float)
    float renderLevel = object->getRenderLevel();

    //Find the location of the component UID in the render order map
    std::map<ComponentUID, std::map<float, std::vector<GameObjectPtr>>>::iterator objectLocation = renderOrderMap.find(uid);

    //If the object doesn't exist in the map
    if (objectLocation == renderOrderMap.end()) {

        //Add a new pair with the component UID and a fresh float/vector map and set the object location to the iterator pointing to it
        objectLocation = renderOrderMap.insert(std::pair<ComponentUID, std::map<float, std::vector<GameObjectPtr>>>(uid, std::map<float, std::vector<GameObjectPtr>>())).first;

        printf("Inserted pair");
    }

    //Get the map at the value of the object location iterator
    std::map<float, std::vector<GameObjectPtr>> objectMapping = objectLocation->second;

    //Find the render level in the map
    std::map<float, std::vector<GameObjectPtr>>::iterator vectorLocation = objectMapping.find(renderLevel);

    //If the object doesn't exist in the map
    if (vectorLocation == objectMapping.end()) {

        //Add a new pair with the render level and a fresh GameObjectPtr vector and set the vector location to the pair's iterator 
        vectorLocation = objectMapping.insert(std::pair<float, std::vector<GameObjectPtr>>(renderLevel, std::vector<GameObjectPtr>())).first;

        /*
        *  These two should equal the same value, because they should call the same method on the same object
        */
        printf("Mapping size: %i", objectMapping.size());   //Outputs 1
        printf("ExtraMapSize0: %i", renderOrderMap.find(uid)->second.size());   //Outputs 0
    }

    //Add the game object to the vector
    std::vector<GameObjectPtr> objectVector = vectorLocation->second;
    objectVector.push_back(objectPtr);

}
```

The problem is near the bottom with the two printf statements. In theory they should point to the same object, but the first call returns a different value to the second.

Is there just a problem with my code, or am I fundamentally misunderstanding something about how iterators work?

Comment: Why didn't you test `.second` on the return value of `map::insert`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::map<float, std::vector<GameObjectPtr>> objectMapping = objectLocation->second;
```

This copies `objectLocation->second` into a new map called `objectMapping`. `objectMapping` is a new object, that's copy-constructed from `objectLocation->second`.

```
    vectorLocation = objectMapping.insert(...
```

This inserts a new value into the `objectMapping` object.

```
    /*
    *  These two should equal the same value, because they should call the same method on the same object
    */
    printf("Mapping size: %i", objectMapping.size());   //Outputs 1
    printf("ExtraMapSize0: %i", renderOrderMap.find(uid)->second.size());   //Outputs 0
```

No, they're not the same object. They are different objects. This is not calling the same method of the same object, but the same method of two different, independent objects. And that's why you're not getting the same value.

I'm going to guess that you were originally a Java developer, and you're now learning C++. This is how objects work in Java, but they don't work like that in C++. You declared a new object called `objectMapping`, copy-constructing it from another object, the value in another map.

If you really wanted them to be the same object, you have to make `objectMapping` a reference.

```
std::map<float, std::vector<GameObjectPtr>> &objectMapping = objectLocation->second;
```

Comment: I've done more Objective-C than Java over the past few years, so I really don't know how I haven't run into this before. I mean, I figured pretty much immediately that this was the case, it's just I somehow didn't know that using & fixes it

Comment: It would not be accurate to merely state that "using & fixes it". A more accurate statement would be "using references fixes it". Gratuitously slapping & anytime you think you have the same problem is unlikely to have productive results. It is important to understand how C++ objects work, and that includes the topics of pointers, references, and scoping. Understanding how the ***entire*** C++ object model works is key to writing correct code.

Answer (score 0):

But you are not printing the same thing.

The first `printf` call prints the size of `objectMapping` which is a `std::map`

The second call prints the size of a *vector* from `renderOrderMap`.